# Show different modules dependence on user role

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I uwrite app and now i have question - lets say i write app for restaurant.

And i need that this app can login chief and waiter  and restaurant owner

Now chief need see only orders.
And waiter need see orders, and table.
and owner need see orders, money tables and lets say count of people

So we have Money, orders, table, people modules.

So I don't want to write for each "player" app - I want all `modules` in 1 app but to do like [Attribute] for pages.

I come from .NET web - so in `WebAPI` I just put `[Authorize(Roles="Owner")]` for example

But i dont find example how i can do something like it in `xamarin`

Thank you

Comment: You can't magically do this. You have to program it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in mechanism to do this in Xamarin.  You would need to code this yourself in your app based on whatever security/role mechanism that you are using.

If you are using MVVM navigation it should be fairly easy to add this sort of check into your navigation mechanism so that users are not allowed to navigate to pages they are not authorized to view.